# 6D $(1,0)$ supersymmetry from properties of 6D spinors

Tags: supersymmetry, superconformality

It is known from string/M-theory considerations that six dimensional superconformal field theories exist with $(1,0)$ supersymmetry.

But if one looks at Table 2.4 on page 47 of Sergio Cecotti's book, ''Supersymmetric Field Theories: Geometric Structure and Dualities", one finds that $(1,0)$ is not an entry for $d = 6$ in the list of physically allowed supersymmetries. The link to the table is https://books.google.com/books?id=qpiiBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false. One can similarly also look at page 42 of Cecotti's notes (available at http://people.sissa.it/~cecotti/partsI-IIv4.pdf), on which this book is based.

Am I missing some point here? I would expect a $d = 6$ $(1,0)$ SUSY theory to have 4 multiplets with 8 supercharges (a SUGRA multiplet, a tensor multiplet, a vector and a hypermultiplet). Why is this entry missing from the book and notes above?

Comment: He is using a different counting convention. What he calls 6d (2,0) supersymmetry is more commonly called (1,0) supersymmetry. Unambiguously, these are theories with 8 real supercharges.

Comment: Thanks @user81003! Is this different convention more clearly stated somewhere, in your knowledge? How does it work in general? This is probably a trivial question, but I am trying to make a list of all $\mathcal{N}$ and $(\mathcal{N}_L, \mathcal{N}_R)$ values which are allowed and the corresponding multiplets, and organizing this list according to the number of (real) supercharges would be very useful.

Comment: See the footnote on page 79 of Cecotti's book. For a nice summary of supersymmetry multiplets in various dimensions see Polchinski's String Theory Vol. 2 Appendix B, or perhaps Freedman and Van Proeyen's Supergravity book. It's just a different convention. Some people write the 6d superconformal algebras as $\mathfrak{osp}(6,2|2\mathcal{N})$, some write $\mathfrak{osp}(6,2|\mathcal{N}')$.

Comment: Oh, nice. Thank you again! I didn't get that far, I should've read further.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is notation. Usually people use the number $\mathcal{N}$ to count the number of supersymmetries such that when $\mathcal{N}=1$ or $(1,0)$ we have the smallest possible supersymmetry.

In $d=5+1$ a chiral spinor will be of the form $\chi^{I}$, with $I=1,\dots,4$ being a fundamental representation of $SU^{*}(4)$. The supercharges must close under complex conjugation $(\chi^{I})^{*}=\Omega_{IJ}\bar\chi^{J}$, and since the complex conjugation matrix $\Omega_{IJ}$ is anti-symmetric and squares to $-1$ it is impossible to use a single chiral spinor $Q^{I}$ and impose a Majorana constraint $\bar Q^{I}=Q^{I}$, without forcing $Q^{I}=0$.

However, if we have two chiral spinors $Q^{I}_{a}$, with $a=1,2$, it is possible to construct the following constraint:

$$
(Q^{I}_{a})^{*}=\varepsilon^{ab}\Omega_{IJ}Q^{J}_{b}
$$

Note that this constraint relates the spinor $Q_{1}^{I}$ with the complex conjugation of the spinor $Q_{2}^{I}$, and vice-versa. If we define $\bar \chi^{I}_{a}=\varepsilon_{ab}\Omega^{IJ}(\chi^{J}_{b})^{*}$ the constraint above becomes

$$
\bar Q_{a}^{I}=Q_{a}^{I}
$$

This $SU(2)$ symmetry becomes the $R$-symmetry if we dimensionaly reduce this $d=1+5$ theory into a $d=1+3$ theory. We can also break this $SU(2)$ symmetry by picking $Q_{1}\equiv Q$ and $Q_{2}\equiv\bar Q$ and constructing a single unconstrained chiral spinor $Q^{I}$, with 4 complex components and 8 real components. If we parametrize the breaking of this $SU(2)$ by an harmonic variable $SU(2)/U(1)$, before dimensional reduction to $d=1+3$ we obtain the harmonic superspace formalism.

Usually people call this pair of two chiral spinor obeying the constraint above, or the equivalent single chiral unconstrained spinor, by $\mathcal{N}=(1,0)$, a theory with 8 supercharges in total.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question was answered a few years ago in the comments, but of course I appreciate your interest :-). It is better to say that the spinors as transforming in a spinor representation of Spin(1,5) just for clarity. Further, I would not use the phrase "supercharges must close under complex conjugation": the property you write down is a basic fact of life for irreducible spinors of Spin(1,5). Thanks for the comments about harmonic superspace -- although I'm not sure what you mean by the phrase "an harmonic variable $SU(2)/U(1)$".

Comment: I mean an $SU(2)$ matrix $u^{a}_{b}$ splitting into $(u^{a}_{+},u^{a}_{-})$. An analytical $d=1+5$ superfield will obey $D_{+}^{I} \Phi=0$, where $D_{\pm}^{I}\equiv u^{a}_{\pm}D_{a}^{I}$, and once we dimensional reduce this superfield to $d=1+3$ it will become a G-analytical superfield.